# Review notification doesn't refresh on review

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queue

When you see the little round (or square on IE) orange blob on the SE top-bar (do these things have better names) it shows you have reviews pending.

Once you've made a review, it doesn't refresh, or if it does it does so very slowly. I know the site uses AJAX, so I don't see why this would be impossible to implement.

Is this [status-bydesign](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or is it a flaw?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150113/update-the-suggested-edits-number-when-i-approve-or-reject-an-edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For suggested edit reviews, which I believe is what you are refering to, this has been reinstated.

There also was a pending review count in the tab header of other review queues at one point, but it has been disabled for performance reasons.

(per [a developper's answer on the main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150113/update-the-suggested-edits-number-when-i-approve-or-reject-an-edit/151897#151897))

Comment: I like their proposed solution. Turn on when you're reviewing. That's what I call sound software development - optimize so stuff Works Well Enough.